# how do you do an upper "-" in programming?

Tags: windows

I'm following a tutorial on youtube , installing rchlinux

anyways he issues a command using an upper - , i haven o idea how he did that , its not on the keyboard
I'm really stuck

Comment: What do you mean by an "upper -"?

Comment: Do you mean like this: ā

Comment: If you mean Arch Linux, how is this a Windows question exactly? In fact, how is it a functional programming question either?

Comment: In some fonts `~` can look suspiciously like `⎺`...

Comment: What keyboard layout are you using? Where is your computer from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You mean [extended ASCII code 238](http://www.theasciicode.com.ar/extended-ascii-code/macron-symbol-ascii-code-238.html) (¯)
- In Windows you can enter characters using ASCII-Codes pressing ALT and typing the number on the Num-Block. For example

  - hold ALT
  - type 238 on num-block
  - release ALT
  - See the result: ¯

Comment: There is no ASCII code 238 - ASCII only goes up to 127.

Answer (score 1):

There is a character `⎺` at Unicode code point `U+23BA`, known as horizontal scan line 1.

I'm assuming here you're installing Arch Linux - your question is unclear on this, it mentions some "mythical" rchlinux but has Windows and Functional Programming tags, the latter which seems *totally* out of place.

If you are indeed installing Arch Linux, you can get that character (in GTK+ systems like my Debian) by *holding down* <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>SHIFT</kbd> together while pressing the individual characters `u23ba` in sequence, then releasing <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>SHIFT</kbd>.

Another way is pressing and releasing <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>SHIFT</kbd><kbd>u</kbd>, then entering the individual keystrokes `23ba<ENTER>`.

Methods for some other environments can be found [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_input).

Even if it's a *different* Unicode character, you can still use this method, you just need to know the hexadecimal code point.